# How can you fix no sound from hdmi or audio out jack? Ubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: hdmi

I can not get any sound from audio out or HDMI. There is no option to set the output at the top right of screen.

```
$ pulseaudio

E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
```

Comment: Please give more information. Is it a laptop? Is it dual-booted? If it is dual-booted, then does audio work on windows-10? Did your audio suddenly stop working?

Comment: My computer is a desktop an is dual booted and the audio works fine with windows 10 on the audio jack and on the HDMI. By the way I had the same issue with Ubuntu 16.04 and was able to resolve the issue by downloading update packages with command codes in the terminal. @ Marmayogi

Comment: Please issue the command `mv ~/.config/pulse ~/.config/old_pulse`. **Reboot** your system. Now, please check your audio. If it fails, then try this command `sudo alsa force-reload`. **Reboot** your system. Now again check for audio. Also please post the output of `pulseaudio` command.

Comment: I entered the command and I got the message mv: missing destination file operand after '/home/(my username).config/old-pulse' @ Marmayogi

Comment: The Destination part of the output appears as `. /home/(my username).config/old-pulse` which is wrong. The correct one should be  `/home/(my username)/.config/old-pulse`. Please don't type the command. Just copy the entire command from my comments and paste it on your terminal. Please try again.  Did you attempt to run the other command? What was the result? Besides, what was the output of the command `pulseaudio`?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean in the first sentence. I copied and pasted the command, and I can get sound from the audio jack, however I would like to be able to select sound to HDMI occasionally from the top right menu, like I could in Ubuntu 14 and 16. The command pulseaudio gets an output of  pid.c: Daemon already running. and main.c: pa_pid_file-create() failed. And when I unplug the audio jack I get sound from computer itself and would rather not ever have that. @ Marmayogi

Comment: I also have a problem with HDMI and VGA not configuring properly after bootloader setup in dual boot If HDMI is plugged in it does not work and VGA is zoomed  in too far. If I wait till ubuntu is loaded an dplug HDMI in it all works fine. @ marmayogi

Comment: Restart the computer and press `shift` key continuously until you enter into GRUB menu. Type `c` and enter into GRUB command line. You will see `grub >` prompt. Enter `videoinfo` and observe the output. There will be a list video modes displayed and one of the mode would be prefixed with a `*`. Note down that video resolution. Also at the bottom, there will be display of `preferred mode` and note down the resolution indicated. Press `Esc` key and go back to GRUB menu. Now boot by choosing `Ubuntu`. Please post the results.

Comment: Issue command `alsamixer` which is a tool to configure sound settings and adjust the volume. To exit just press `Esc`. Use arrows keys (Up/Dn and Lt/Rt) to navigate as well as the adjust volume. First `unmute` Headphones by pressing `M`. Also disable `Auto mute`. Adjust volume levels of **Front** and **PCM** and check you get audio. Refer this [tutorial](http://www.linuxplanet.com/linuxplanet/tutorials/7134/1) for more details.

Comment: Using GUI tool `Settings -> Sound`,  try to adjust `output volume` and check audio jack out with head phones. Also check HDMI port for audio. Also make use of `Test Speakers` available at the bottom of the screen. Besides,  check the output by `adjusting` the control at the top right of screen.

Comment: I have resolved the sound issue thanks to you Marmayogi! However, keep in mind I run dual boot with windows 10 as I stated before so you confused me a lot with the pressing the shift button which is useless I am already in the bootloader menu at start but ok. It would help if everybody actually read all posts and comments. So I get an output of   0 x 162  848x    480 x 32 (3392)   Direct color mask:  8/8/8/8  pos:(6/8/0/24  and preferred mode 1920 x 1080      Adapter 'VGA Video Driver  No info Available @ Marmayogi

Comment: Can you please post your video issue as a separate question?

Comment: nobody answered it the first time i posted it